# Why does this video say that /aɪ/ is to glide from /ɑ/ to /i/?

Tags: pronunciation

look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjYVGAKQMdI

It said that to pronounce /aɪ/, we need to glide from /ɑ/ to /i/

/i/ long

/ɪ/ short

In the above video, they don't teach /a/ sound but only /ɑ/ sound

Anything wrong with this video?

Comment: Did you see the part where it says _in the video itself_ that, “These are general guidelines. For example, some argue for /ɪ/ instead of /i/”? Phonemic writing is not necessarily very accurate. They write /æ/ and /ɑ/ as the two ‘a’ phonemes; they might just as well have written them /æ/ and /a/, or indeed /a/ and /ɑ/. The important thing is that the start of /aɪ/ is phonetically most like (though not necessarily completely identical to) the latter, the low mid vowel that they call /ɑ/. The latter one is debated and varies—some have [i], some [ɪ], some [i̯].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is something wrong.  The video is confusing.  For clarity, we ought to distinguish sounds, customarily written with brackets, from phonemes, customarily written with slashes.  I think that what is meant is that to pronounce the phoneme /aɪ/, we need to glide from the sound [ɑ] to the sound [i].  I'm not sure that is true, really, but I think it is what is meant.  The representation of phonemes is to some extent conventional and does not need to correspond directly to pronunciation.  The phoneme /aɪ/ is not made up of phonemes /a/ and /ɪ/.